# Ошибка при использовании модели h5

Tags: tensorflow, keras

При попытки использования модели появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/marik/PycharmProjects/Emomusic2/emo.py", line 4, in <module>
    model.predict("test.jpg")
  File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\Emomusic2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1598, in predict
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\Emomusic2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1100, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\Emomusic2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 643, in __init__
    self._internal_adapter = TensorLikeDataAdapter(
  File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\Emomusic2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 273, in __init__
    num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(inputs)).pop()
  File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\Emomusic2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 273, in <genexpr>
    num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(inputs)).pop()
  File "C:\Users\marik\PycharmProjects\Emomusic2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 889, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key].value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Код:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
print("[INFO] model has loaded")
model.predict("test.jpg")
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: А что на вход `predict` должно подаваться? Не думаю, что название файла )))

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло однако выходит другая ошибка: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer DCNN is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (32, 960, 3)`.

Comment: Вам нужно зарешейпить байтовый массив с картинкой, добавив в него одно измерение (пустое). Ибо на вход предполагается массив картинок, а у вас картинка одна. Попробуйте так: `x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)`

Comment: Более подробно тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/43019294/8324991